# Performance of image vs custom drawing in UIKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, core-animation

I have a UITableCell that has a few gradient layers and drop shadows in it. I'm wondering if it would be more performant to handle this with coreanimation layers or just use a a single background image for the cell?

In general is it more performant to use large images (with transparency) over core animation? What's the best way to test the difference? I'm guessing Instruments would be involved. Also I'm looking for a good resource on iOS performance testing and best practices. 
Sorry for the multiple questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images vs. Core Graphics.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520320/images-vs-core-graphics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, using images is always faster than drawing manually.

Comment: Is there a known reason for this or is it just what the results show?

Comment: @Christian, I'm sorry, your question is actually a duplicate. I've given this answer before. The accepted answer of that question explains it pretty well: "CG is not terribly slow, just slower than filling a graphic buffer with a bitmap."

Comment: Do you have a link to that question?

Comment: Yes, it's the question I linked as a duplicate. Anyway, here's the link again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520320/images-vs-core-graphics

Comment: My bad. I didn't see it up there.