# Hardware-accelerated scaling on iOS without OpenGL

Tags: ios

I'm currently writing an iOS backend for a cross-platform program whose platform-independent engine writes all of its graphics into 32-bit pixel buffers, in RGBA order. The alpha byte isn't used. The graphics are always opaque so I don't need alpha blending.

What is the most efficient option to draw and scale these pixel buffers to my `CGContextRef` inside my `drawRect` method? The pixel buffers are usually only 320x240 pixels and need to be scaled to completely fill my view's dimensions, e.g. 1024x768 on non-Retina iPads and 2048x1536 on Retina iPads. This is a whole lot of work so it's best done using the GPU. But how can I force iOS to draw and scale using the GPU without using OpenGL?

I've tried using `CGContextDrawImage()` but this is really slow, probably because everything is done using the CPU.

I've also had a look at the `CIImage` APIs because these are apparently GPU optimized but the problem is that `CIImage` objects are immutable so I'd have to constantly create new `CIImage` objects for each frame I need to draw which will probably kill the performance as well.

I could go with OpenGL of course but I'd like to get some feedback on whether there is an easier solution to get what I want here.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I think the next links will show you some hints. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520320/images-vs-core-graphics and https://robots.thoughtbot.com/designing-for-ios-graphics-performance and https://lobste.rs/s/ckm4uw/a_performance-minded_take_on_ios_design/comments/itdkfh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the easiest way to do this is to simply create a `CGImageRef` from the pixel buffer using `CGDataProviderCreateWithData()` and then `CGImageCreate()`. This `CGImageRef` can then be set as the view's layer, like so:

```
view.layer.contents = (id) myImage;
```

The image will then be automatically scaled (with GPU acceleration) to fit the `UIView`'s frame if `contentMode` is set to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` (which is the default).

Thanks to David Duncan from the Cocoa mailing list for suggesting this solution!